# Eliminate a string patter into an xml file and add a Number

Tags: powershell

I would like to know if someone can help me out with this. 
I would like to replace the content into the string `<channel id="I123.15676.schedulesdirect.org">` after `=` and in between the `" "` for a Number starting from `1000` and so on progressively

Example: 
Original: `<channel id="I123.15676.schedulesdirect.org">`
Replacement: `<channel id="1000">`

```
<channel id="I123.15676.schedulesdirect.org">

<channel id="1000">
```

also recursively into another file that instead of having `channel id=` have the same content into the variable `tvg-id=`

So this is my sample.xml file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">
<tv source-info-name="vaders.tv" generator-info-name="VaderEPG" generator-info-url="epg.ninja">
<channel id="I123.15676.schedulesdirect.org">
        <display-name>RDS HD</display-name><display-name>RDS</display-name>
        <display-name>123 RDS</display-name>
        <display-name>123</display-name>
        <display-name>R&#233;seau des Sports (RDS)</display-name>
        <icon src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/schedulesdirect/assets/stationLogos/s15676_h3_aa.png" />
    </channel>
<programme channel="I123.15676.schedulesdirect.org" start="20180404030000 +0000" stop="20180404033000 +0000">
        <title lang="en">Sports 30 [New!]</title>
        <desc lang="en">Soyez au courant des plus r&#233;cents d&#233;nouements dans le monde du sport. Directement des studios RDS et sur le terrain, l'&#233;quipe de "Sport 30" analyse en profondeur les r&#233;sultats des derni&#232;res 24 heures dans toutes les disciplines. Hockey, football, baseball, Formule 1, rien n'&#233;chappe &#224; nos animateurs qui discutent &#233;galement des dossiers chauds tels les rumeurs d'&#233;change, le rep&#234;chage des futurs espoirs, les scandales reli&#233;s au dopage, etc. Sans oublier une dose d'humour avec quelques gags bien plac&#233;s par ces collaborateurs de longue date et la fameuse compilation des plus beaux jeux du jour. De l'action en toute saison.</desc>
        <episode-num system="dd_progid">SH00168398.0000</episode-num>
        <new />
        </programme>
```

and this is the second file sample.m3u which contains the same  identified as  to match the sample.xml

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="I123.15676.schedulesdirect.org" tvg-name="RDS HD" tvg-logo="http://vod6.vaders.tv80/logos/rds.png" group-title="Sports",RDS HD

http://vaders.tv/live/xyz/xyz/57579.ts
```

This is the start of the code which i really have no idea how to properly apply it

```
[xml]$xml = get-content "C:\sample.xml"
$xml.SelectNodes("//channel") | foreach{$_.id = "1001"}
```

My intention here is to identify the tvg-ID="abc" , channel id="abc" , programme channel="abc" which are the same and simultaniously change these
for "1000", Then the following  tvg-ID="etx" , channel id="etx" , programme channel="etx" for "1001" and so on...

Thanks again guys!.

Comment: Can you please share any code you got so that we can have a look? Thank you! :)

Comment: @kim Sure, 
The first File content is
<channel id="I401.49609.schedulesdirect.org">

The second File Content is
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="At The Races" tvg-id="I415.30505.schedulesdirect.org" tvg-logo="http://vod6.vaders.tv80/logos/at%20the%20races.png" group-title="Sports",At The Races

Comment: Import your xml with [xml](get.content -path "%your path%") and the use xPath like this $xml.selectnodes("//channel") | foreach{$_.id = "1001"}

Comment: @carloslozada: Edit your question, share the sample file with the piece of code that you have tried. Give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Original question edited.